# BitmapMetadata causes overflow saving metadata when there is already a lot of data

Tags: c#, metadata, jpeg, keyword, exif

I'm writing some image (jpeg) metadata to the image.
The issue - I was receiving issues on some files: "The image data generated an overflow during processing." trying to save some new metadata, in this example keywords.

*Most importantly the question is how to do it "right" avoiding .NET to fail. But I'm also providing temporally fix on how to solve this issue as I've seen related unsolved questions.*

I've been trying to solve this issue for some time, but today I found the cause. Some programs such as Photoshop write A LOT of data to the xmpmeta section. So when I execute code like:

```
*//...prepare metadata before*
BitmapMetadata JpegMeta = JpegDecoder.Frames[0].Metadata.Clone() as BitmapMetadata;
var s = string.Join(";", parms.Keywords.ToArray());
///THIS STANDRAT ONE generates OVERFLOW on some images ~1-2% 
JpegMeta.Keywords = new ReadOnlyCollection<string>parms.Keywords.ToArray());
//Bellow is doint ghe smae manually  
//Following GENERATES OVERFLOW on some images ~1-2%:
JpegMeta.SetQuery("System.Keywords", parms.Keywords.ToArray()); 
JpegMeta.SetQuery("/xmp/dc:subject", new BitmapMetadata("xmpbag"));
for (int i = 0; i <= parms.Keywords.Count - 1; i++){
    string sOrder = "/{ulong=" + i + "}";
    string key = parms.Keywords[i];
    JpegMeta.SetQuery("/xmp/<xmpbag>dc:subject" + sOrder, key);
    //Following GENERATES OVERFLOW on some images ~1-2%:
    JpegMeta.SetQuery("/xmp/<xmpbag>MicrosoftPhoto:LastKeywordXMP"+sOrder, key);
    //Following GENERATES OVERFLOW on some images ~1-2%:
    JpegMeta.SetQuery("/xmp/<xmpbag>MicrosoftPhoto:LastKeywordIPTC" + sOrder, key);
}
JpegMeta.SetQuery("/app1/ifd/{ushort=18247}", Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(s));
JpegMeta.SetQuery("/app1/ifd/{ushort=40094}", Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(s));
*//...save metadata further*
```

It fails to save.

This code addresses all the possible section and approaches I know to save metadata (especially with keywords different programs tend to use or prioritize different modern and legacy sections, so we have to write to all of them).

This error showed itself only on some files. I noticed the issue when I opened "bad" files with notepad and manually copied and examined xml rdf sections of them and the ones from "good" ones. What I found out that Photoshop, Camera Raw etc. write a lot of information regarding what has been don to the image. Sometimes it takes many pages to scroll which in turn results in causing .NET to fail. So if I delete some data, for example running such command:

```
JpegMeta.RemoveQuery("/xmp/crs:PaintBasedCorrections");
```

I get my queries work. I can look in the file and remove many other that are likely won't be used by anyone.

But this approach is bad because first of all I'm removing some data that may be needed for someone in some scenarios, but most importantly I don't know which section will be too big next time. If someone close and open PSD file 1000 times it will cause 1000 section on image history recorded and saved to JPEG and .NET will fail again when I want to use this file.

Suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: You say *"It fails to save"*, but I fail to see error message. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: There is no question "why isn't this code working". I've described the issue, situation and even the cause why is it happening. I'll try to specify futher: "Fails to save" means BitmapMetadata throwing overflow exception iff jpeg contains certain ammount or more of metadata (put there by some other applications such as Photoshop) when I save it. Basicly it llooks like large XML inside JPEG. It looks like.NET bug when class does not handle large but possible size of metadata section. Question is how to write metadata in this case without delleting some parts of existing one.

Comment: Percise error is "The image data generated an overflow during processing." on JpegEncoder.Save(JpegStreamOut);

Comment: Each JPEG tag containing metadata can hold a maximum of 64K. Is it possible you're asking it to store more than that and it's not smart enough to break it up into pieces?

Comment: Not sure if XMP section does limited in size. It is XML and as far as I understood from spec there is no limitation unlike legacy sections which are limited and stored as binary data. Just to be clear we are speaking about this section: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Metadata_Platform Even If I write what is already there it will throw and exception. Don't think that Adobe would violate it's own standart by writing too much.

Comment: Yes, XMP is XML data, but it still resides in a JPEG tag which only has a 16-bit length. "Smart" software which writes more than 64k of data will split it up into multiple APPxx tags, but "dumb" software will probably throw an exception.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Could you please link to some file that has splited xml data? Not sure how it could look like.

Comment: Looks like you are right. Found in http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/xmp/pdfs/XMPSpecificationPart3.pdf  Following the normal rules for JPEG sections, the header plus the following data can be at most 65535 bytes
long. If the XMP packet is not split across multiple APP1 sections, the size of the XMP packet can be at most
65502 bytes. It is unusual for XMP to exceed this size; typically, it is around 2 KB. If the serialized XMP packet becomes larger than the 64 KB limit, you can divide it into a main portion (StandardXMP) and an extended portion (ExtendedXMP).

Comment: Then the right question becomes is it possible to do this split using standart .NET classes.

Comment: Sorry, I don't use .NET classes. I wrote my own imaging library in C/ASM. Sounds like Microsoft support would be a good place to ask.

Comment: Thank you for comments. The issue become more clear.